# Referring to specific list item with hyperref

Tags: hyperref, longtable

using the following code, when I click on references (having red boxes), they do not refer to proper places.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\theenumii{\alph{enumii}}
\makeatletter
\def\subitem{\omit\@arstrut 
\ifnum\value{enumii}=0 \stepcounter{enumi}\fi
\refstepcounter{enumii}\theenumi\theenumii\hfill}
\def\item{\omit\setcounter{enumii}{0}\let\omit\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{longtable}{>{\refstepcounter{enumi}\setcounter{enumii}{0}\theenumi}lr}
\item
\subitem \label{1a}& fooo \\
\subitem \label{1b}& foo \\
\item
\subitem \label{2a}& foo \\
\subitem \label{2b}& foo \\
\label{3}& foo  \\
\label{4}& foooo \\
\end{longtable}

we have \ref{1a}, \ref{2b}, \ref{4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Be careful in using `\subitem` as a command name, since it's used in the `theindex` environment. All's well until you need to make an index, when disaster might be approaching.

Comment: @egreg yes well he got that code from me in the previous question.:-) Once it's working the thing to do really is put the `\item` and `\subitem` definitions into the start code of a custom environment just before starting longtable, to keep the scope of the redefinition local.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two problems:

- The anchor names are not unique. This can be fixed by redefining `\theHenumi` and `\theHenumii`.
- The anchor position is the baseline. The anchor is set by `\refstepcounter`. This can be cured by `\raisebox{\ht\@arstrutbox}[0pt]{...}`. But then `\refstepcounter` is called inside a group and the meaning of `\@currentlabel` (what `\ref` sees) and `\@currentHref` (anchor name, if option `localanchorname` is used). Therefore these values are put into global scratch variables to restore them after `\raisebox`.

The example file with update for adding parentheses and the dot. And another update for bold numbers in the table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage[verbose]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\theenumii{(\alph{enumii})}
\renewcommand*{\theHenumi}{\theenumi}
\renewcommand*{\theHenumii}{\theenumi\alph{enumii}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\raiserefstepcounter}[1]{%
  \raisebox{\ht\@arstrutbox}[0pt]{%
    \hypersetup{localanchorname}%
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \global\let\g@currentlabel\@currentlabel
    \global\let\g@currentHref\@currentHref
  }%
  \let\@currentlabel\g@currentlabel
  \let\@currentHref\g@currentHref
}
\def\subitem{%
  \omit\@arstrut
  \ifnum\value{enumii}=0 %
    \stepcounter{enumi}%
  \fi
  \raiserefstepcounter{enumii}%
  \bfseries
  \theenumi\theenumii.\hfill
}
\def\item{%
  \omit
  \setcounter{enumii}{0}%
  \let\omit\relax
}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\begin{longtable}{%
  >{%
    \raiserefstepcounter{enumi}%
    \setcounter{enumii}{0}%
    \bfseries\theenumi
  }l<{\unskip.}r%
}
\item
\subitem \label{1a}& fooo \\
\subitem \label{1b}& foo \\
\item
\subitem \label{2a}& foo \\
\subitem \label{2b}& foo \\
\label{3}& foo  \\
\label{4}& foooo \\
\end{longtable}

we have \ref{1a}, \ref{2b}, \ref{4}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: thanks for sorting that out, I asked the OP to ask another question rather than adding a hyperref constraint on the previous one.

Comment: thanks.
in the table, we have `1a`, `1b`, for example. how can i set them to `1(a).`, `1(b).`. also, in the body of text, when we want to refer to these items, we would have `we have 1(a) and 1(b)`. it would be preferable not to use `\renewcommand{\theenumii}{...}`

Comment: @shm It is unclear to me, what you want to have in the table, with/without parentheses, with/without dot?

Comment: @Oberdiek  i want `1(a).`, `1(b).`, `2.`, ... in the table (list items). and when referring to these items out in the body of text, i want `we have 1(a) or 1(b) or 2`, for example.

Comment: @Oberdiek thanks a lot. as an extension, could we have numbers in 1'st column of table in bold, and blue colored form?

Comment: @smh Answer updated for bold numbers in the table.